# How to get all requests sent by the website with JSOUP

Tags: jsoup

I'm not sure JSOUP is able to do this, but i would like to see the requests the website is making.

When i load particular website there is a GET requests that automatically fires, but is hidden by JS in html code.

If JSOUP is not able to do this, any other libraries i can use?

For kotlin android programming

Comment: you can use htmlunit It has fairly good JavaScript support

Comment: Already tried HtmlUnit and it was unable to load page fully, somehow they are obfuscating the needed links, unfortunately

Comment: you have to add   webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(1000);